# How to prevent programmatically started python script from exiting command prompt after error?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have to start a few different python programs every so often, so I am trying to create one "master" script that I can run that will automatically start all of the others using `subprocess.Popen`.

The problem I am running into is when one of the programs has an error, instead of the command prompt staying open so I can read and correct the error, it automatically closes.

Here is my code.

```
import subprocess
print "Starting programs"

args = "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program1.py"
subprocess.Popen(args)

args = "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program2.py"
subprocess.Popen(args)

args = "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program3.py"
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

I have looked into `os.system` as well but I couldn't find anything that would allow for this.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? Are you running from a terminal/console window or double-clicking to make it go?

Comment: Your program runs all of the commands in parallel and doesn't wait for them to complete. Do you want to run them that way?

Comment: Hi. I asked the questions for a couple of reasons. One is that a command prompt shouldn't close just because a program it executes terminates abnormally.... depending on what you mean by "command prompt" of course.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I'm running it on Windows. I am running the "master" from a console window, but the scripts that it proceeds to open are acting as if they were double clicked (closing on error)

Comment: @tdelaney I just need it to start the other program. They each take a couple of hours to run so I don't want it to wait for them to finish.

Comment: That's puzzling. That shouldn't happen if they are just command line programs. Are they GUIs or are you using the Windows `start` command in there somewhere? I can't figure out where the windows are coming from.

Comment: They are not GUIs, and I'm not using the start command. The code I'm running is exactly the same as what I posted above. It's strange, I'm not sure why they don't stay open.

Comment: are you  saying each `subprocess.Popen` creates a new console in your case? (i.e., there are 4 consoles: "master" and 3 `ProgramX.py`?)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, that's correct. The "master" opens up three new ones for each of the ProgramX.py

Comment: Are you sure you use the code from the question? What are Python, Windows versions? To workaround it, you could use `cmd /K "python ..ProgramX.py"`  command to keep the windows open. Call `p.terminate()` to exit (`p = Popen(..)`).

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. It opens up three python.exe windows. Those are the windows that close after the program finishes/errors, and that I am trying to keep up so I can see what the program outputs.

Comment: I just tried what you mentioned though and it seems to work as I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't print the output of the subprocess, that is why you don't see the exception.
To solve this, just add a **try-except** block for every program you want to run to see all exceptions and print the output of each program to see if it fails, like this:

```
import subprocess


def run_programs():
    try:
        args = "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program1.py"
        out = subprocess.Popen(args)
        print out
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Error in Program1.py: {}'.format(e)

    try:
        args = "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program2.py"
        out = subprocess.Popen(args)
        print out
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Error in Program2.py: {}'.format(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting programs"
    run_programs()
```

If you want to run a lot of programs a for loop will be more practical as pointed out by Padraic.

```
import subprocess


def run_programs():
    cmds = [
        "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program1.py",
        "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program2.py"
        "python C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Program3.py"
    ]
    for cmd in cmds:
        try:
            out = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
            print out
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Error in {}: {}'.format(cmd, e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting programs"
    run_programs()
```

Comment: a loop with a list of commands with one try/except would be more practical

Comment: This only catches exceptions when trying to start the program (e.g., file not found). I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm looking for is a way for it to keep the command windows that subprocess opens, open until I manually exit them.

Comment: `try/except` in the parent won't catch exceptions in the child processes (apart from those errors that are explicitly passed by `subprocess` module before the child is executed).